# How to make sums from a cell in another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, numbers, excel-2010, excel-2007

I'm looking for a issue to make automatically sums of 10 cells from the raw of the high value of another column
. 
I explain the job :

I have to enter data in a table.

2 columns and 113 rows.

the A column is data export. And B is sum of 10 cells from the high A column value. The sum is every 10 cells.

On the screenshots the yellow cell is the high value. I have to make sums every 10 cells (grey cells) from the yellow one.

[image]

[image]

7 sums are report on another table :

[image]

For the moment I have to report all values manually. I'm looking for make and report sums automatically. Is it possible?

The problem is, according to the data report in the A column, the high value (yellow cell) is not at the same place. So the values for the sums are not at the same place too...

Do you have an idea?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**REVISED:**

Let me know if this is something you are looking for:

[image]

The **updated** formula you enter from `cell B2` is:

```
=IF(OR(ROW(E4)<MATCH(LARGE($E$4:$E$57,1),$E$4:$E$57,0)+ROW($F$3)+10,MOD(ROW(E4)‌​-(MATCH(LARGE($E$4:$E$57,1),$E$4:$E$57,0)+ROW($F$3)+10),10)>0),"",SUM(OFFSET($E$3‌​,(MATCH(LARGE($E$4:$E$57,1),$E$4:$E$57,0)+1)+((ROW(E4)-(MATCH(LARGE($E$4:$E$57,1)‌​,$E$4:$E$57,0)+ROW($F$3)+10))),,10)))
```

This should work even you add/remove your top rows.  Also, you just need to change that `10` to any number sums you want to do and it should still work.

Basically I have to first use `LARGE` and `MATCH` to find out the largest number in the column, and then use `OFFSET` to find every 10 rows to sum up.  Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I edited my question.
I made a translation mistake between average and sum sorry.

Comment: It is a little bit hard to understand your translated question but you can change the formula (array formula) to `=IFERROR(SUM(AVERAGEIFS($A$2:A2,$A$2:A2,LARGE(IF($A$2:A2>0,$A$2:A2),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}))),0)` and it should work.  I can edit my answer if this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just edited the question to be understanding.
I added concret sceenshot.

Comment: @Haox, I just updated my answer but wasn't able to upload a pic for you to view.  But try the formula first (regular formula) and let me know if that works or not.

Comment: I just try this (with french formula) : 

`SI(OU(LIGNE(E4)<EQUIV(MAX($E$4:$E$117,1),$E$4:$E$117,0)+11, MOD(LIGNE(E4)−(EQUIV(MAX($E$4:$E$117,1), $E$4:$E$117,0)+11),10)>0),"",SOMME(DECALER($E$4,(EQUIV(MAX($E$4:$E$117,1),$E$4:$E$117,0)+1)+((LIGNE(E4)−EQUIV(MAX($E$4:$E$117,1),$E$4:$E$117,0)+11))),,10)))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156291/discussion-between-ian0411-and-haox).

Answer (score 0):

This will find the max and start the running average from that:

```
=IF(AND(MOD(ROW(),10)=MOD(MATCH(MAX(A:A),A:A,0)+1,10),ROW()>MATCH(MAX(A:A),A:A,0)),AVERAGE(A1:INDEX(A:A,ROW()+9)),"")
```

Comment: I just edit the question to be more acurate in my demand.
thank you for your help